# Action with errors 401 in all requests

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

In all requests in the application, if an error occurs *401*, need to perform a certain action.
I do not want to handle this action in every request manually.

Is it possible to solve this moment at the *OkHttp* level so that it immediately applies to all requests at once?

**Retrofit and OkHttp class:**

```
public class RestApi {

    public final User user;
    private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

    public static final String TAG = "RestApi: ";

    @Inject
    public RestApi(PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper) {
        this.preferenceHelper = preferenceHelper;

        TokenAppendingHeaderInterceptor tokenInterceptor = new TokenAppendingHeaderInterceptor();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Const.Url.API)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        user = retrofit.create(User.class);
    }






    public class TokenAppendingHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            String token = preferenceHelper.getToken();
            Request newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader(Const.Url.COOKIE, token)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }


    public String getCookiesFromResponse(Response response) {
        String cookies = "";
        List<String> listCookies;
        try {
            listCookies = response.headers().toMultimap().get("Set-COOKIE");
            cookies = CookieHelper.getStringCookies(listCookies);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getCookiesFromResponse: BITRIX can't send cookies");
        } finally {
            return cookies;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Headers for Authentication in request
In your code  `TokenAppendingHeaderInterceptor` class in method Intercept add the  hweaders like this
r

```
equest.addheader('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
request.addheaders('Authorizcation', 'Basic '+btoa(username + ':' + password));
```

I think it will help you